Action button to run macro if condition is met
I have a "Balance" worksheet that aggregates values for:

Trip price
Driver fee
Guide fee
Driver paid (YES/NO)
Guide paid (YES/NO)

I have an "Accounts Payable" worksheet where I calculate the owed values to each employee based on a pivot table where fields "Driver paid" or "Guide paid" are set to "NO" (filter on the pivot to "NO").
I then have a macro that goes to the pivot table and sets the filter to "NO" so that the correct values can be displayed in the "Accounts payable" worksheet.
Finally, I have an action button to run the macro whenever I want it to. Everything works just fine, as long as there is a "Driver paid" or "Guide paid" field set to "NO", otherwise the macro tries to set the pivot filter to "NO" and, surprise, surprise, it can't because there's no "NO" value there.
I thought about setting a control sum that is 0 when no "NO" value is present and is not 0 when any "NO" is present. The idea is that when I press the action button, if the control sum is not 0 then the macro runs normally, if the value is 0 then nothing happens (I have a macro called "Do Nothing" that simply changes to the "Accounts Payable" worksheet).
This is the bit I'm struggling with: how do I get the action button to pick which macro to run, depending on a cell value?

Pseudo code: If (or(Driver paid = "NO",Guide paid = "NO") then run macro Else alert user / run Do Nothing?

If countif("No"Range, "No") = 0 Then // Macro1 // Else // Macro 2 // End If ?

Thank you both to @cybernetic.nomad and Cyril but I don't know how I can associate any of these two bits of code to my action button.

How did you associate the current code with the button?

Not via code, I just added the action button through Excel's "Developer" menu and then "Insert", "Form Controls", "Button". The next dialog asks to which macro I want to associate the button, and that's it

Convert the pseudo code into a macro and do the same thing.

We're definitely getting there. but I'm getting stuck with the RUN command, not sure what the syntax should be to get VBA to recognize my macro name as a macro callout.
I'm taking a step-by-step approach and I'm using this code
If "Driver Paid" = "NO" Then Run "Update_Drivers" Else MsgBox ("Nothing To Update").
My ELSE is working, I do get the message box, but my RUN isn't. The UPDATE DRIVERS macro isn't being called.
What am I doing wrong?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/call-statement
